# How to force recreation of moved files where the changeset broke

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have the situation where I had a folder in my solution renamed and then stored onto TFS. In another commit I deleted the old folder. Now my problem is that the order of things broke the changesets unexpectedly. Thus when I get latest version I have the correct new folders with all files EXCEPT the project files themselves.

Even when I manually copy in the old project files into the new folders TFS says there was no change made. And thus I can't recreate those project files into the TFS.

Now my question is if there is any way to force TFS to see that these files NEED to be put into the repository?

Comment: Try going to the Team Explorer -> Pending Changes - " Excluded Changes" - press Detected: xxxx add(s) -> See if you can find your files here -> "Promote"

Comment: That was it exactly. (I needed to "promote" them to full adds. tnx. In essence you answered my question there if you make the commentto an answer I'll accept it. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Promote your changes (in Git it would be "Git add *").

Team Explorer -> Pending Changes -> "Excluded Changes" -> press Detected: xxxx add(s) -> Find your project files -> Promote

Comment: Accepted. Tnx again. Would have never guessed that TFS would take those chagnes only as "possible" changes and you need to promote them to real changes for TFS to get it correctly  without your comment/answer. tnx again!